# How to setup a association through multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've the followig three models in `Rails`:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :chapters
    has_many :pages
end

class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :book
    has_many :pages
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :chapter
end
```

How is it possible do to a query like: `Book.first.pages.count` to get the number of pages of the whole book. By now I dont even know if i set my model up the right way. Would be great if you could help me out here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a `has_many` `through` relationship as outlined [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :chapters
    has_many :pages, through: :chapters
end

class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :book
    has_many :pages
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :chapter
end
```

That enables you to do `book.pages.count`

Answer (score 0):

The issue may lie in your data model. The associations as listed seem a little odd - a `Book` has many `Chapters` and many `Pages`, but a `Chapter` can also have many `Pages`. How do you differentiate between the `Pages` in a `Book` compared to a `Chapter`?